# Foundation 6 display elements inline

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am struggling with this issue. I am try to show the elements next to each other(horizontally) but i can't achieve this behaviour.

HTML:

```
<span>
<p>Enter text:</p>
<input type="text" name="">
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.span{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Span is inline,you need not make any change they will be side by side

Answer (score 0):

Just make this change

```css
span *{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span>
<p>Enter text:</p>
<input type="text" name="">
</span>
<span>
<p>Enter text:</p>
<input type="text" name="">
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

well we have some problems here ..

first u need to be more carefull with the css selector you use (`.span` referes to a `class` named *span*..not the `span element`) and i guess [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) link may help well.

and 2nd is that you are styling the span but you need to style the elements that you want to be next to each other and i strongly recommand that you read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp) too.
and as your answer here are the

HTML

```
<span>
    <p class="a">Enter text:</p>
    <input class="b" type="text" name="">
</span>
```

and CSS

```
.a{
    display: inline-block;
}
.b{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

this way you should get what you wanted to.

Comment: I used dev console and saw this line : "div {
    display: block;
}"  and it says "user agent stylesheet" to it's right